# Ignore parameter in stored procedure If null

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get a multi input search function on a table to work via stored procedure.

I have four input parameters: a bool and 3 strings. When I run 1 string and a bool I get back the expected row.

As soon as I try to add the 2 and 3 inputs (string) to the search I get back no data. If I have all 3 inputs (strings) filled in it should return the rows that have something related to those strings.

If the input is empty...then it should just skip that part of the query

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUsers]
    @Online BIT = NULL,
    @UserName NVARCHAR(150) = NULL,
    @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(150) = NULL,
    @Location NVARCHAR(50) = NULL
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM Users
    WHERE (ISNULL(@Online, 0) = 0 OR (@Online = 1 AND Online = 1)) 
      AND (ISNULL(@UserName, UserName) = UserName OR UserName LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%' )
      AND (ISNULL(@EmailAddress, EmailAddress) = EmailAddress OR EmailAddress LIKE '%' + @EmailAddress + '%')
      AND (ISNULL(@Location, Location) = Location OR Location LIKE '%' + @Location + '%' )
    ORDER BY 
         Users
    FOR XML PATH('Users'), ROOT('Users')

    RETURN 0
```

Comment: What does "I get back a Root element is missing" mean? Side note: this type of query is called a [Kitchen-Sink query](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example), and for performance reasons should probably have either `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or dynamic SQL. You should also change the logic to `(@UserName IS NULL OR UserName LIKE '%'+@UserName+'%')` etc

Comment: I'm assuming it has to do with there being no values so it returns no xml

Comment: I don't think this error is coming from SQL Server, because it should just return null if there are no rows. Why it's not returning rows is your real question. If `UserName` in the row is null and `@UserName` is also null, then your code becomes `NULL = NULL` which is always false

Comment: You could also build up a nvarchar sql statement and execute it using `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WHERE  (  (@Online Is Null) or  (@Online = 1 AND Online = 1))
      AND ( (@UserName is null)  OR (UserName LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%' ) )
      AND (( @EmailAddress is null) or ( EmailAddress LIKE '%' + @EmailAddress + '%'))
      AND ( (@Location is null)  or   ( Location LIKE '%' + @Location + '%' ))
```

Comment: I tried this previously but if I have a value for Username and Emailaddress...If the username is in one row, but email is in another row...it doesn't return any results.  It should show two rows...the row with the username and the row with the email.